# Calling remote method in spring with parameters

Tags: java, spring

I have a class annoted with Service Annotation on server 1 .

```
@Service
public class MainHandler implements AbstractHandler {

   @Autowired
   private ServiceLocal defaultService;

   @Override
   public boolean execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws MsisdnServiceException {
          System.out.println("The default Request" + request);
   }
}
```

I want to call this method from other remote server after passing the request and get the response from this  , what is the way to do in spring .

Comment: downvoting because no research done, not a difficult question with research, and confusing remote methods and HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking methods remotely would be using a technology called RMI, which you can google easily.

However, since you want to use HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse, you probably should write an Http Controller using Spring MVC. For that you can also google and very easily find excellent tutorials and guides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spring's `RestTemplate` to make communication with the servers.

First you need to create a controller on `server 1` backend to get data from `server 2`:

```
@RestController
public class MyController { 
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    String execute(@RequestBody MyClass object) {
          System.out.println("Your data" + object);
        }
    }
```

On `server 2` backend create a method that make a REST call to `server 1`'s endpoint with `RestTemplate`:

```
void request() {
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/endpoint";

    HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    httpHeaders.set("Content-Type", "application/json");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("name", "yourName");
    json.put("email", "name@gmail.com");

    HttpEntity < String > httpEntity = new HttpEntity < String > (json.toString(), httpHeaders);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String response = restTemplate.postForObject(url, httpEntity, String.class);
}
```